# Setting the default calendar in iOS?

Tags: ios, calendar

In the calendar app (iCal?) in iOS, is it possible to set a default calendar?  Every time I go to add a scheduled event when I am at work, it picks the wrong calendar to add it to, and if I could just set a default I could save alot of time on that.

Comment: On naming - confusingly the iOS calendar is called 'Calendar' while OS X's calendar is called 'iCal'. Maybe it'll change in Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Settings -> Mail Contacts Calendars - > Calender -> Defaultcalendar